# A MailItem saved in the ItemSend Event is saved as draft

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm developing an Outlook add-in that allows the user to save an email to the filesystem just after it's been sent.

To achieve this, I intercept the Application.ItemSend event, and inside my handler I call MailItem.SaveAs(...). It works, basically.

The problem I'm facing is that, when I open the file saved, the email is in draft state. I mean, the recipients, subject and message body can be modified, and the email can be resent. I want the email to be in "sent" state, i.e. not modifiable.

It looks like Outlook API does not provide any event dispatched **after** the email is sent. Only **before**, and this is my pain.

Do you have any idea to perform this?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Nico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the earliest you can save the message in the sent state and with the sender properties populated is when `Items.ItemAdd` event fires on the Sent Items folder.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thanks for your proposition; I tried a few days ago and noticed it was not reliable... And with this solution, is it possible to handle redirection rules? I mean, if the item is redirected to a folder outside the Sent Items folder... Thanks!

Comment: Items.ItemAdd is pretty reliable unless you get more than 16 or so emails added at once (pretty had to do with the Sent Items folders). If the item is supposed to be saved to a different folder, you can check MailItem.SaveSentMessageFolder in the Application.ItemSend event and create an event sink on that folder too if it is not the default Sent Items folder - you can use a Dictionary (entry id vs Items object) to store extra Items objects to process events on.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry; I read somewhere else on SO that it was crucial to keep a reference on the MAPIFolder.Items in order to avoid event disconnection. You wrote this actually :). I made a customer test this solution and it behaves pretty good. Thanks a lot!